# Should we always track query and db errors?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want to know if everytime we do a connection to the database,
or a query, we must track the errors like:

```
if (!$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', ''))
    echo 'Error: (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error;
} else { ... }


if (!$mysqli->query('CREATE DATABASE mywebsite'))
    echo 'Error: (' . $mysqli->errno . ') ' . $mysqli->error;
} else { ... }
```

I'm doing a bunch of queries and some db connections, so should I always proceed like this?, it's a bit tiring though :/

Any advices from those with experience on handling a bunch of queries and db connections, would be welcome. Do you always do this everytime for each of these to track the possible errors?

What if you skip some and track the most important?

Comment: Well, a bit tongue-in-cheek, if you don't care if some database accesses succeed or not, a simple optimisation is probably to just remove them.

Comment: Technical errors are only intended for the developer as they can reveal sensitive information for attackers.

Comment: You could use `error_log()` instead of `echo`, so the details are not sent to the end user.

Comment: You should track all the information and only the information that is important to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should we always track query and db errors?

### YES, YES and YES!

Tracking error *messages* is a **cornerstone** of a programming. A programmer is a helpless baby in the woods without error messages.

However, the way you choose for tracking is a terrible one.

There are **two** destinations for the error messages:

- on a development server it's very handy to show them on-screen
- but on a live server they **ought to be logged**

So, you have to make your tracking code able to do both. Thus,

### NEVER EVER echo an error message directly.

Use built-in PHP mechanisms instead - either raise an error or exception.

```
if (!$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', ''))
    throw new Exception( $mysqli->connect_errno . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

if (!$mysqli->query('CREATE DATABASE mywebsite'))
    throw new Exception( $mysqli->error );
}
```

This way you will have reliable and convenient reporting system, that can be controlled with **single PHP configuration option**.

So, on a local development server configure PHP this way:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

and you'll be able to see all the error messages on-screen
While on a live server you have to track them all too, but log them instead:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',0);
ini_set('log_errors',1);
```

Despite of a common delusion, **for a live server error messages are WAY more important** than for a development one. So, neither `error_reporting(0)` nor `@` should be ever used with an excuse of "not showing error messages to the user". Don't want to *display*? Turn off *displaying*, but not error messages themselves.

To ease everyday usage of `mysqli_query()`, this function have to be encapsulated into some user-defined function or method - so, you'll be able to call it with just

```
$db->query('CREATE DATABASE mywebsite');
```

with all the error handling job done internally - that's the only proper way to avoid manual error handling yet have it always on duty.

And, regarding `"some db connections"` - there should be only **one** (with same credentials) throughout entire application. Put connection code into some bootstrap file which you include in all your pages.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are asking because you don't want to clutter your code with error handling I would like to add the following to the answer given above.

I am always using wrapper libraries around the native database functions in PHP even if I am not using a full-blown MVC framework. They do all the error handling for me, help me avoiding sql injection and so much more.

So I suggest that you have a look at one of the following components:

- Zend DB (can be used without Zend Framework, this [blog post](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/zend-framework-2-cheat-sheet-zenddb/) explains how
- Doctrine DBAL - This is part of the Doctrine ORM, and e.g. used in microframeworks like 
  Silex and of course full-blown frameworks like symfony2 - see [this blog post for an introduction](http://jwage.com/post/31080076112/doctrine-dbal-php-database-abstraction-layer)

In either case learning to use one of those libs  is not lost time - you will see them most probably again in other PHP projects.